# approaching php class member inside jquery function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm quite new in jquery so it's probably a basic I skipped. Anyway, I don't find an answer. I have a php class that one of its attributes (coming from the database) is the font color of the page text. I want to use it in jquery in the `$(window).load` function, but get some kind of mistake in any way I try it. Here's the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).load(function(e) {
        $("#storyTR").addClass('<?php echo($story_obj->font_style) ?>');
        $("#titleTR").addClass($("#Bg").val());
    });
}
```

and the relevant php code:

```
class Story
{
    public $title;
    public $story;
    public $img;
    public $body_class;
    public $font_style;

    function __construct()
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=sipurim;charset=utf8','root','100995',
        array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => 
        PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

        foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM stories WHERE row_id='. $_GET["Story"]) as $row)
        {
            $this->title = $row['title'];
            $this->story =  $row['story'];
            $this->img = $row['Img_url'];
            $this->body_class =  $row['Body_Class'];
            $this->font_style =  $row['Font_Style'];
        }
    }
}

$story_obj = new Story;
```

Comment: somekind of error ... what is that error?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The error doesn't show on the page, but what should happen (the font gets white) doesn't happen and when I'm viewing the page source here's what I get

Comment: with the info you give we cant do anything for a white page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the window.load (and it is not needed) is the error, use:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#storyTR").addClass('<?php echo $story_obj->font_style; ?>');
       $("#titleTR").addClass($("#Bg").val());
   });
```

There is also an error in your original javascript which might also be the issue. Need the error.

Comment: This would definitely throw a syntax error. And usually you don't use () for a language construct.

Comment: Oops fixed Charlotte (forgot to look at the php given the error in the javascript)

Comment: Either it's `<?=$story_obj->font_style ?>` or `<?php echo $story_obj->font_style; ?>`

Comment: Of course, I noticed the lack of a ; right away :) I use Smarty generally so I never have to worry about those.

Comment: sorry for not understanding - where is the lack of ;?

Comment: When you do echo you do not use ( ) but instead you echo the variable with `echo variable;`, so you need to finish the line with a ; (which I had forgotten originally for the example)